# Symfony2 - How do i validate the Type directly in the Form?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, constraints

I'm following this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

And added this to my form:

```
    $builder->add('email', null, array('label' =>  'userType.label.email','constraints' => array(new Email())));
```

This works perfectly fine.

But the following does not work:

```
    $builder->add('phoneNumber', null, array('label' =>  'userType.label.phoneNumber','required'  => true,'constraints' => array(new Type(array('type' => 'numeric')))));
```

How can i check if the input is numeric, right in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this:

```
->add('phoneNumber', 'integer', array('label' =>  'userType.label.phoneNumber','required'  => true));
```

When you pass `null` it will use the type you set in the model, is just a way to pass the 3rd parameter without overriding the second one.

Comment: By the way in this specific case you may want to use a regexp validator in a string type, a phone number may have semantic issues which are easier to deal with using regular expressions than just a number.